# How can I use an android zip in oracle VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, android, iso-image, zip, emulation

I want to use an android O image. The problem is the downloads [(Here)](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html) are in a compressed zip format and VirtualBox requires and iso image. How can I emulate the zip?

Answer (score 0):

The downloads you've linked are Android system images - they are not disc images (ISO files) and cannot be mounted as such.

If you are having difficulty transferring the compressed image file from your host to the VirtualBox guest, the best way would be to [install VMware Tools in the guest operating system](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Windows_10.html#Tools). After doing so, you can transfer the compressed images via [Drag and Drop](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_dragndrop.html) or [Shared Folders](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html) in VMware.